# why pouchdb.rel.find() works only with integer id?

Tags: reactjs, couchdb, pouchdb, relational-pouch

I am trying to fetch related record with the help of  pouchdb.rel.find('') it works fine when i give integer id it fetch the related data, but i don't give integer id while storing and give same id generated by couch db it is not working then

this  will work

```
pouchdb.rel
  .save('staff', {
    title: 'Rails is Unagi',
    text: 'Delicious unagi. Mmmmmm.',
    id:5
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    return pouchdb.rel.save('agent', {
      description: 'nice masculine jawline',
      staff: data.id
    });
  });
```

but this will not work

```
pouchdb.rel
  .save('staff', {
    title: 'Rails is Unagi',
    text: 'Delicious unagi. Mmmmmm.',
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    return pouchdb.rel.save('agent', {
      description: 'nice masculine jawline',
      staff: data.id
    });
  });
```

As i can not give id manually every time, maybe i am missing some please guide me about it what i am doing wrong here

this is full file i am working on

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
//import some adapter
import find from 'pouchdb-find';
import rel from 'relational-pouch';

// import { bulkStaaff } from './bulk';

PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-adapter-http').default)
  .plugin(require('pouchdb-authentication').default)
  .plugin(require('pouchdb-adapter-indexeddb'))
  .plugin(find)
  .plugin(rel)
  .plugin(require('pouchdb-replication'));

const remotedb = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/siloc');
const pouchdb = new PouchDB('siloc');

// const db = new PouchDb('http://localhost:5984/siloc');
pouchdb.setSchema([
  { singular: 'staff', plural: 'staffs', relations: { agent: { belongsTo: 'agent' } } },
  { singular: 'agent', plural: 'agents', relations: { staff: { belongsTo: 'staff' } } },
  { singular: 'ranchOwner', plural: 'ranchOwners', relations: { staff: { belongsTo: 'staff' } } },
  { singular: 'rightHandMan', plural: 'rightHandMen', relations: { staff: { belongsTo: 'staff' } } },
  { singular: 'independentContractor', plural: 'independentContractors', relations: { staff: { belongsTo: 'staff' } } },
  { singular: 'packagingCompany', plural: 'packagingCompanies', relations: { staff: { belongsTo: 'staff' } } },
  { singular: 'cuttingCompany', plural: 'cuttingCompanies', relations: { staff: { belongsTo: 'staff' } } },
  { singular: 'truck', plural: 'trucks', relations: { staff: { belongsTo: 'staff' } } },
  { singular: 'boss', plural: 'bosses', relations: { staff: { belongsTo: 'staff' } } }
]);

remotedb
  .sync(pouchdb, {
    live: true,
    retry: true
  })
  .on('change', function (info) {
    // handle change
    console.log(info);
  })
  .on('paused', function (err) {
    // replication paused (e.g. replication up to date, user went offline)
    console.log(err);
  })
  .on('active', function () {
    // replicate resumed (e.g. new changes replicating, user went back online)
  })
  .on('denied', function (err) {
    // a document failed to replicate (e.g. due to permissions)
    console.log(err);
  })
  .on('complete', function (info) {
    // handle complete
    console.log(info);
  })
  .on('error', function (err) {
    // handle error
    console.log(err);
  });

// bulkStaaff.forEach((staff) => {
//   pouchdb.rel.save('staff', staff);
// });

// pouchdb.rel
//   .save('staff', {
//     title: 'Rails is Unagi',
//     text: 'Delicious unagi. Mmmmmm.',
//     id:5
//   })
//   .then((data) => {
//     console.log(data);
//     return pouchdb.rel.save('agent', {
//       description: 'nice masculine jawline',
//       id: 1,
//       staff: data.id
//     });
//   });
console.log(pouchdb.rel.find('staff','F8AD62DF-C70B-BEA3-B42F-639013CECC23'))

export { pouchdb, remotedb };
```